# Attaching mean Longitude and Latitude to specific counted labels

Tags: r, dataframe, count, unique, mean

I have a dataset of crimes in London and I made a subset of it which resulted in the columns: long, lat, LSOA.code . (820 entries) 
I want mean long and lats of the 32(found out by count function)- different LSOA.codes. How do I specify this?

```
#subset data to relevant long-lat and type of polygon
london_crim_sub = subset(london_crim, select = c(5,6,8))
#remove missing
london_crim_sub = remove_missing(london_crim_sub)

library(dplyr)

DF = data.frame(count(london_crim_sub$LSOA.code))
```

So i want a dataframe like this: columns: 
LSOA.code, freq, meanlon, meanlat

I found the freq, using the count. Now i only need to get the unique mean long and lat per LSOA.code with different freq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to group by the LSOA.code and produce mean latitude and longitude? We can update the DF dataframe you've already created:

```
DF$meanlat <- aggregate(lat ~ LSOA.code, london_crim_sub, mean)
DF$meanlon <- aggregate(lon ~ LSOA.code, london_crim_sub, mean)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
london_crim_sub %>%
         group_by(LSOA.code) %>%
          summarise_at(vars(lat, lon), list(mean = ~mean(.))) %>%
         select(-LSOA.code)%>%
         bind_cols(DF, .)
```